# How to create a docker-machine with aws driver with a key-pair that already exists

Tags: docker, docker-machine

How can I create a docker-machine with an amazon key-pair that already exists? It expects a keypath which is the local path to the private key, but there seems to be no way to specify that this keypair already exists in this aws region and it tries to create a new keypair everytime

Comment: I haven't found a solution to this yet, and neither have these guys: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1898 . The solution may be to connect docker-machine to an existing EC2 instance somehow

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `--amazonec2-keypair-name` option. For example,

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-keypair-name=my_key_pair new-machine
```

See [Amazon Web Services | Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/aws/#options) Options section.

Comment: you need to also add the `--amazonec2-ssh-keypath` option which refers to the key.pem file path in your local file system
P.S. the private and public keys should be in the same folder (i.e. key.pem and key.pem.pub)